# .NET Split Arraylist based on values

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, arraylist

I have a datagridview of books with that structure:
The grid has 3 columns publication, author and title.
There might be repeated records in that grid.
There are 5 publications in data.

I want to split data based on publication and therefore assign the values to 5 variables So I first sorted and added all values to an arraylist but I don't know how to split them.

```vb
Structure abb
    Public publications As String
    Public author As String
    Public title As String
End Structure

Public arlist As New ArrayList
Public thebooks As New abb

For i As Integer = 0 To Databook.Rows.Count - 2  'databook is the gridview
    With thebooks 
        .publications = CStr(Databook.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        .author = CStr(Databook.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        .title = CStr(Databook.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
    End With
    If Not arlist .Contains(thebooks) Then
        arlist .Add(thebooks)
    End If
Next i
```

Now I made the arraylist but in that list there are 5 publications which have one or more books in them.
 I want to have 5 arraylists based on publication name **(5 variables at the end).**

I might went the first step wrong because I guess there is another way to do that at first from datagridview rows... .

NOTE: VB or C# answers could help me find my way.

Comment: Any reason why your `ArrayList` isn't instead a `List(Of abb)`? That will simplify the code that splits it by removing the need to cast/unbox those structs.

Comment: There is no reason. I did what I could to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

i still dont know exactly what you want, you mean that "publications" can have values likes these:

abb.publications = "Book A, Book B, Book C"?

if yes what do you want to do with them? or you just  want to group abb by a book name inside publications? something like this? (Using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397926.aspx))

First i think you can change `Public arlist As New ArrayList` to `Public arlist As New List<abb>` as suggest by Simon. and then after your For:

```
Dim books = abb.SelectMany(Function(b) b.Split(",")).Distinct().ToArray();
Dim abbByBookName = books.Select(Function(b) arlist.Where(Function(a) a.publications.Contains(b))).ToArray()
```